# what is reloadData function?

Tags: iphone, tableview

every one.
I'm a new for iphone.

I saw some document for iphone develop, but 
I don't understand the [xxx reloadData]; with tableView yet.

When i use this method, my all cells are cleared. 
What happened?

I don't understand it.

Comment: Wait... You knew Apple documents their classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you force the `UITableView` to get the data and refresh itself. It is what you wanna do after you changed something in your data source.

For example, I have a `NSMutableArray` of three objects a, b and c. I have a button to delete an object, say b. After I pressed my button and get object b deleted from my array, my table view won't reload unless I call `[myTableViewName reloadData]` to force it refresh itself.

If after you do `[xxx reloadData]`, you got nothing. It means, your data needed for the table view is not there anymore. So track the data source and see if the data got changed.

Comment: I want to use func reloadRows(at indexPaths: [IndexPath], 
           with animation: UITableViewRowAnimation), I have only one section in the table view and I know which row I need to update...but IndexPath is not an int...how can I set indexPath here

Answer (score 2):

As the documentation indicates, `reloadData` will simply force the list to refresh by querying your datasource and delegate. Please see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html and post some code if you have problems.