# Sending data from Google Places API to tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places-api

How send data to tableview in iOS with objective-C? I am trying to solve my problem very long time but result is not correct. My tableview is still empty. What I'm doing wrong? Below is my implementation file.

```
import "PlacesViewController.h"

@implementation PlacesViewController
@synthesize places;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set this view controller object as the delegate and data source for the table view
    self.listTableView.delegate = self;
    self.listTableView.dataSource = self;
}

-(void)queryGooglePlaces
{
    //Build the url string to send to Google
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.503186,-0.126446&radius=5000&types=food@|restaurant|bar&keyword=vegetarian&key=myOwnKEY"];
    url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@", url);

    //Formulate the string as a URL object.
    NSURL *googleRequestURL=[NSURL URLWithString:url];

    // Retrieve the results of the URL.
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: googleRequestURL];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self fetchedData:data];
        });
    });
}

-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:responseData

                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];

    //The results from Google will be an array obtained from the NSDictionary object with the key "results".
    self.places = [json objectForKey:@"results"];

    //Write out the data to the console.
    NSLog(@"Google Data: %@", json);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.places count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *tempDictionary= [self.places objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you update the datasource, you need to call `[self.tableView reloadData]`

So it should be like this

```
-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:responseData

                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];

    //The results from Google will be an array obtained from the NSDictionary object with the key "results".
    self.places = [json objectForKey:@"results"];

    // NOTE - ADDED RELOAD
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    //Write out the data to the console.
    NSLog(@"Google Data: %@", json);
}
```

For more information about `reloadData` see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10823449/2956647)

Comment: Thank you. But I cannot try your solution because I have new problem. I see "Thread 1: breakpoint 3.1" comunicate in line to return the number of rows in the section in tableview: return [self.places count];. Do you know idea why?

Comment: that means result of `[json objectForKey:@"results"]` is not an `NSArray`, please NSLog and check the request result

Comment: I've only changed NSLog(@"Google Data: %@", json); to NSLog(@"Google Data: %@", places); and problem with "Thread" disapointed. But my tableview is still empty...

Comment: try logging, before `[self.tableView reloadData]`

Comment: What does it mean "try logging"? Sorry, I'm beginner and I don't know where I have to logging in this case...

Comment: :) okay, remove `[self.tableView reloadData]` line, and run again

Comment: I removed this line as you told and nothing changed. Still I haven't data in rows my tableview...

Comment: that's ok, but what prints the log?

Comment: Nothing print the log... Maybe I should add something in 'viewDidLoad' method?

Answer (score 0):

After you update the data source you should reload the table view.

```
self.places = [json objectForKey:@"results"];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```